# Error training network with Python and Pytorch

Tags: python, pytorch

I'm test driving this library on my mac with a very simple example, but I get the following error:

> NotImplementedError: The operator 'aten::_unique2' is not current
> implemented for the MPS device. If you want this op to be added in
> priority during the prototype phase of this feature, please comment on
> https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/77764. As a temporary fix,
> you can set the environment variable `PYTORCH_ENABLE_MPS_FALLBACK=1`
> to use the CPU as a fallback for this op. WARNING: this will be slower
> than running natively on MPS.

Below the code (applied to the Portugal bank benchmark dataset).

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from pytorch_tabular import TabularModel
from pytorch_tabular.models import CategoryEmbeddingModelConfig, NodeConfig, TabNetModelConfig
from pytorch_tabular.config import DataConfig, OptimizerConfig, TrainerConfig, ExperimentConfig
from pytorch_tabular.categorical_encoders import CategoricalEmbeddingTransformer

# Read diamonds dataset

bank = pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/carlosquintanillaa/Tidymodels-Regression/main/Data/bank.csv")
bank.drop('job',axis=1,inplace=True)


# Function to prepare data (data splitting, declaration of categorical variables and dependent variable)

def prepare_data(df,target_col,test_size):
    torch_data = np.array(df.drop(target_col,axis=1))
    torch_labels =np.array(df[target_col])
    data = np.hstack([torch_data, torch_labels.reshape(-1,1)])
    gen_names = [f"feature_{i}" for i in range(data.shape[-1])]
    col_names = gen_names
    col_names[-1] = "target"
    data = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=col_names)
    cat_col_names = [x for x in gen_names[:-1] if len(data[x].unique())<10]
    num_col_names = [x for x in gen_names[:-1] if x not in [target_col]+cat_col_names]
    test_idx = data.sample(int(test_size * len(data)), random_state=42).index
    test = data[data.index.isin(test_idx)]
    train = data[~data.index.isin(test_idx)]
    return (train, test, ["target"],cat_col_names,num_col_names)

# Apply function to diamonds dataset

train, test, target_col, cat_col_names, num_col_names= prepare_data(bank,'y',0.2)


# Set up network

data_config = DataConfig(
    target=['target'], #target should always be a list. Multi-targets are only supported for regression. Multi-Task Classification is not implemented
    continuous_cols=num_col_names,
    categorical_cols=cat_col_names,
    continuous_feature_transform="quantile_normal",
    normalize_continuous_features=True
)

trainer_config = TrainerConfig(
    auto_lr_find=True, # Runs the LRFinder to automatically derive a learning rate
    batch_size=1024,
    max_epochs=20,
    gpus=1, #index of the GPU to use. 0, means CPU
)

optimizer_config = OptimizerConfig()

model_config = CategoryEmbeddingModelConfig(
    task="classification",
    layers="4096-4096-512",  # Number of nodes in each layer
    activation="LeakyReLU", # Activation between each layers
    learning_rate = 1e-3,
    metrics=["accuracy"]
)

tabular_model = TabularModel(
    data_config=data_config,
    model_config=model_config,
    optimizer_config=optimizer_config,
    trainer_config=trainer_config,
)


# Estimate network (using gpu!!)

tabular_model.fit(train=train,test=test)
```

Comment: BTW I tried: import os
# Set the environment variable
os.environ['PYTORCH_ENABLE_MPS_FALLBACK'] = '1' and I still get the same error.